# Preg replace utf8 charset issue with à

Tags: php, character-encoding, preg-replace

I'm trying to add a special string '|||' after newlines, blankspaces and other characters. I'm doing this because I want to split my text into an array. So I was thinking to do it like this:

```
$result = preg_replace("/<br>/", "<br>|||", preg_replace("/\s/", " |||", preg_replace("/\r/", "\r|||", preg_replace("/\n/", "\n|||", preg_replace("/’/", "’|||", preg_replace("/'/", "'|||", $text))))));
$result = preg_split("/[|||]+/", $result);
```

It works with every word but words which contain **à** char. It is replaced by �.
I'm sure the problem is here because my string $text shows the char à.

Comment: You need the `/u` modifier with each regex.

Comment: If think you have an encoding problem somewhere. To solve it you need to check that all is in UTF-8 (your code file, your string, if any: your html, database, text files...), there're tutorials that explain how to do it without missing any step).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your pattern deals with a  Unicode string, pass the `/u` modifier.

Also, you do not need so many chained regex replacements, group the first patterns and use a backreference in the replacement.

Use

```
preg_replace("/(<br>|[\s’'])/u", "$1|||", $text)
```

Note that `\s` matches spaces, carriage returns and newlines.

**Details**:

- `(<br>|[\s’'])` - Group 1 capturing  either a

  - `<br>` - character sequence
  - `|`  - or
  - `[\s’']` - a whitespace, `’` or `'`.

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/8dKF5y):

```
$text = "Voilà. C'est vrai.";
echo preg_replace("/(<br>|[\s’'])/u", "$1|||", $text);
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about the existence of /u and thank you for having made my code simpler!